# jQuery toggle order

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to toggle some divs and at the same time set an "active" state on the links. Below is my code.

```
$(".product_buy").hide();
$(".product_geo").hide();

$("a.buy, a.geo").click(function()
    {
        $("#" + this.className + "_" + this.rel).slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("item_active");

        if (this.className == "geo")
            {
                $("#info_" + this.rel).slideToggle("fast");
            }

        return false;
    });


<ul class="title_menu">
    <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="geo" rel="blabla" title="Toggle geometry">Geometry</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="buy" rel="blabla" title="Toggle purchase options">Buy</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="product_buy" id="buy_blabla">
    <div class="block">
        <p>Buy bla bla</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product_geo" id="geo_blabla">
    <img src="geo_blabla.jpg" title="Bla bla geometry" width="750" height="857"/>
</div>

<div class="prod_info" id="info_blabla">
    <p>Info bla bla</p>
</div>
```

It toggles, but not all at the same time. It's ok if the two divs "buy" and "geo" is shown at the same time, but the "active" state of the link seems to mess things up.

I'm a noob, so feel free to mock me.

Edit: Solved it before I saw the answer from Nick, so his solution is probably better.

```
    $(".product_buy").hide();
    $(".product_geo").hide();

    $("a.buy, a.geo").click(function()
        {
            var itemType = $(this).attr("rev");
            var itemName = $(this).attr("rel");

            $("#" + itemType + "_" + itemName).slideToggle("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass("item_active");

            if (itemType == "geo")
                {
                    $("#info_" + itemName).slideToggle("fast");
                }

            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a total change in approach here that'll also degrade gracefully without JavaScript.  Use the `href` to go to the element of an ID you want, like this:

```
<ul class="title_menu">
  <li class="item"><a href="#geo" title="Toggle geometry">Geometry</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#buy" title="Toggle purchase options">Buy</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="buy" class="content">
  <div class="block">
    <p>Buy bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="geo" class="content">
  <div>
    <img src="geo_blabla.jpg" title="Bla bla geometry" width="750" height="857"/>
  </div>

  <div class="prod_info">
    <p>Info bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery also gets *much* simpler, like this:

```
$(".content").hide();
$("ul.title_menu a").click(function(e) {
    $(this.hash).slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("item_active");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Kx2ty/1/).  What this does is use that `href="#geo"` as a `$("#geo")` selector to toggle the right element.  The `class="content"` is so we can hide them all...you could also use that same class as a mechanism to only show one at a time (by hiding *other* content elements, [like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Kx2ty/2/).

The other big benefit here is without JavaScript enabled, all divs will show and the links will scroll to the appropriate element...a nice degraded view that still works for the user.

Comment: Hi Nick,

Thank you very much for your answer! I really appreciate it.

I solved it before I went back here to see if I'd received an answer. I'll take a look at your solution the first thing in the morning. Thanks again!